# How to choose column in sql select using variable in Qt

Tags: postgresql, qt

I am writing a function that will take a string variable and work with a column with the name of this variable, but i can't figure out how to write variable in select

I tried this where test is QString variable with value company, but it didnt work like if there was company without variable

```
QString test = "company";
QSqlQuery password = db->exec("SELECT password FROM '"+test+"'");
```

Comment: This quite obviously won't work indeed. Have you at least tried to run this query on e.g. pgAdmin? What about `db->lastError()`, have you inspected it? And BTW, how come you have a pointer to a `QSqlDatabase`? Class `QSqlDatabase` should be instanciated through its static methods like `addDatabase`, as stated in the default constructor; none of the static methods results in a pointer.

Comment: db->lastError() writes QSqlError("42601", "QPSQL: Unable to create query", "ERROR:  syntax error (approximate position: \"'company'\")\nLINE 1: SELECT password FROM 'company'\n

Comment: Solved. It worked without ' '. Here is code line:
QSqlQuery password = db->exec("SELECT password FROM "+test+"");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked with deleted '' of the variable.

```
QSqlQuery password = db->exec("SELECT password FROM "+test+"");
```

Comment: Cool. Now all that is left is protect this code against [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).